# Is it semantic to add css styles to a `center` element?

Tags: html, center

Is it semantic to add css styles to a `<center>` element? So it would be like this `<center style="max-width:600px;display:inline-block;" >`

Background: I'm having to use `<center>` the above markup to make an html email work cross email clients.

Comment: The `<center>` element was removed from HTML a while ago. Don't use it.

Comment: @j08691 im aware of that its only being used as a hack for older email clients (mostly old versions of outlook that reley on old versions of IE as their rendering engine) that break the layout without it

Answer (score 2):

No.

`<center>` is entirely presentational and has no semantics.

The `style` attribute is entirely presentational and has no semantics.

Zero semantics + zero semantics = zero semantics.

It may be worth noting that zero semantics is arguably better than incorrect semantics such as might be introduced by layout tables.